Refused to exec script from 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=' because its MIME type ('image/gif') is not exec
I'm trying to run google adsense on my nextjs 13 project as export using next-google-adsense.
I'm using the manual display ads
I've confirmed that adsbygoogle.js is being loaded
but I get this console error:
Refused to execute script from 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-xxx' because its MIME type ('image/gif') is not executable.
and when I open the link, it's literally just a grey pixel in the middle
but when I open the link again or refresh, it downloads an f.txt file that contains the script
I've searched everywhere but it seems it's only happening to me at the moment.
I expect ads to just loaded properly
EDIT
this is the code in _app.tsx
    <ChakraProvider>
      <GoogleAdSense publisherId="pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" /> {/*  16 digits */}
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ChakraProvider>

this is the code in my home page in one of the components
      <AdUnit
        publisherId="pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        slotId="xxxxxxxxxx"
        layout="display"
      />

my website is at fort7.net
